# Use GetX for Physics Simulation Animation? How to synchronize animationController.value.value with dragAlignment.value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm new to Flutter. I heard that GetX can simplify development. I want to rewrite [Flutter's official physical simulation example](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/physics-simulation) using GetX.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';

//pageview
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Physics'),
        actions: const [
          Row(children: [Icon(Icons.share)])
        ],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DraggableCard(child: const FlutterLogo(size: 128)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// widget's view
class DraggableCard extends GetView {
  DraggableCard({required this.child, super.key});
  final Widget child;
  final logic = _DraggableCardLogic();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = Get.size;
    return GetX(
      init: _DraggableCardLogic(),
      initState: (_) {},
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onPanDown: (details) {
            logic._aniC.stop();
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            logic._dragAlignment.value += Alignment(
              details.delta.dx / (size.width / 2),
              details.delta.dy / (size.height / 2),
            );
            // print(logic._dragAlignment);
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            logic._runAni(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond, size);
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: logic._dragAlignment.value,
            child: Card(child: child),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

//logic&state
class _DraggableCardLogic extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _aniC = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  final _dragAlignment = Alignment.center.obs;
  late final _aniBack = _aniC
      .drive(AlignmentTween(
        begin: _dragAlignment.value,
        end: Alignment.center,
      ))
      .obs;

  void _runAni(Offset pixelsPerSec, Size size) {
    _aniBack.value = _aniC.drive(AlignmentTween(
      begin: _dragAlignment.value,
      end: Alignment.center,
    ));
    print('DRAG:${_aniBack.value}');

    final unitsPerSecX = pixelsPerSec.dx / size.width;
    final unitsPerSecY = pixelsPerSec.dy / size.height;
    final unitsPerSec = Offset(unitsPerSecX, unitsPerSecY);
    final unitVelocity = unitsPerSec.distance;

    const spring = SpringDescription(mass: 30, stiffness: 1, damping: 1);

    final simulation = SpringSimulation(spring, 0, 1, -unitVelocity);
    _aniC.animateWith(simulation);
    // how to synth the state?
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _aniC = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _aniC.addListener(() {
      _dragAlignment.value = _aniBack.value.value;
    },);
    print('init!');
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    _aniC.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

What I want (Flutter Official Demo):

[Official Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzgAh.gif)

My(No reset animation):

[No Reset Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTuOU.gif)

The drag animation has been implemented, but I still cannot implement the reset animation of the physical simulation `_aniC.animateWith(simulation)`

My guess: `_aniC<AnimationController>` is already executing `animateWith(simulation)`, but does not synchronize the `_animation.value.value` to `_dragAlignment.value`, I've tried addListener(){} but that didn't work :(

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I'll learn other package in the future. But I've to learn to use GetX first because I have to make a small demo project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved it by using GetX,below code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class HomeDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: DraggableCardView(),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableCardController extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin  {
  final Rx<Alignment> _dragAlignment = Rx<Alignment>(Alignment.center);

  Alignment get dragAlignment => _dragAlignment.value;

  set dragAlignment(Alignment value) => _dragAlignment.value = value;

  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Alignment> _animation;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      _dragAlignment.value = _animation.value;
    });
    super.onInit();
  }

  void runAnimation(Offset pixelsPerSecond, Size size) {
    _animation = _controller.drive(
      AlignmentTween(
        begin: dragAlignment,
        end: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );

    final unitsPerSecondX = pixelsPerSecond.dx / size.width;
    final unitsPerSecondY = pixelsPerSecond.dy / size.height;
    final unitsPerSecond = Offset(unitsPerSecondX, unitsPerSecondY);
    final unitVelocity = unitsPerSecond.distance;

    const spring = SpringDescription(
      mass: 30,
      stiffness: 1,
      damping: 1,
    );

    final simulation = SpringSimulation(spring, 0, 1, -unitVelocity);

    _controller.animateWith(simulation);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class DraggableCardView extends StatelessWidget {
  final DraggableCardController controller = Get.put(DraggableCardController());

   DraggableCardView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: (details) {
        controller._controller.stop();
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        controller.dragAlignment += Alignment(
          details.delta.dx / (size.width / 2),
          details.delta.dy / (size.height / 2),
        );
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        controller.runAnimation(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond, size);
      },
      child: Obx(
        () => Align(
          alignment: controller.dragAlignment,
          child: const Card(
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 128,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**To Verify below code you can visit this link and watch the video:-**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXQSJrgYzpMjqe-BOrR-OUNuZcyk0KQm/view?usp=sharing

I hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Sincerely thanks! Now I have further understanding for GetX. There are my comprehension:

1. GetXController need getter and setter methods for outside lib reference

2. use addListener for `Animation` and `AnimationController` because GetX has no substitute methods, also no need to set their type to `Rx<>`

3. Obs() returns a Widget, I've not thought to write Align in it so that return the Align in realtime